# Как изменить стиль для первого option в select?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы первый выбранный option имел отличающийся от других стиль? Имеется ввиду не в раскрывающемся списке, а при непосредственном его выборе?

Пример:

Красный цвет заливки для первого option:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Синий цвет заливки для второго option:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
<select required>
    <option disabled selected hidden>Выберите что-то одно</option> 
    <option> опция 1 </option>
    <option> опция 2 </option>
    <option> опция 3 </option>
</select>
```